# Performance Management Tool for 2 or more applications

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, performance-testing, websphere-8

I am working on an enterprise application which earlier used MyEclipse tool for Java / Java EE development, EJB 2.1 and WAS 7.0, recently we migrated to EJB 3.1, Websphere 8.5.5 and Eclipse Kepler. Now, we have noticed the performance of the application has increased and the screens load faster.

Now the problem that I am facing is to compare the earlier application with the one we've upgraded to and identify those areas which has led to speed up of the application. There are no performance metrics recorded for this application till date so I don't have anything to compare with.

All I am thinking was to have the Pre-Upgraded application deployed on a box and the Post-Upgrade application on the other box and record the time of load of all the screens. Now, this is not as subtle as being thought, so would like to know from you guys if there are any tools or strategies to compare two working applications and give performance metrics based on EJB methods time, JSP load time, Business Logic time, Database operations which gives true benefit analysis of the upgrade.

Also, do you guys think upgrade of application server and Integrated Development Environment (Eclipse Kepler) might have contributed to this speed?

Comment: I think you are expecting a very easy way for all things, which is not available and though some tools give some analysis which is not meaningful in finding exact improvement and predictions. Having round a detailed perf. testing is always beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have both environments (WAS 7 and WAS 8.5.5) and some load scripts, I'd suggest to use PMI ([Performance monitoring infrastructure](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tprf_tpvmonitor.html?lang=en)) in WAS. You can enable metrics that interests you, set data to be saved to the log and run tests on both environments. Then you will be able to see gathered metrics for both environments.

The other option could be free [WebSphere Application Server Performance Tuning Toolkit](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/performtuning.html), which can be used to gather the performance data. Available either as standalone (older version) or as plugin to IBM Support Assistant (ISA).

> Could upgrade of application server and Integrated
>   Developement Environment (Eclipse Kepler) might have contributed to
>   this speed?

Sure. The WAS 8.5.5 is in general faster than v7.0. For example it by default is using genCon garbage collection policy, which in most cases is more efficient that optthroughput.
The dev environment has no impact on application runtime performance, but maybe it is more responsive during development and thats why you have the 'faster' feeling.

Comment: Thanks. The application performance has been seen increasing in higher environments like SIT and Sandbox so its not that its the Dev which is giving the 'faster' feeling. Don't you think enabling PMI on WAS console will make server slow while running as it has log everything?

Comment: @YogendraJ It doesn't log 'everything' if you dont set it to `All`. The impact for Basic and Extended is about 2-4%, so not really big. Otherwise it wouldn't make sens to use it as performance metrics. And you can always use the `Custom` option and enable only these you really need (but I'd probably start with extended and see if it has all you need and the performance is acceptable).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the options available.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is benchmarking of both the versions of application and then compare both to see improvement.

for comparing both versions follow below approach,

1. Deploy both versions on exactly similar hw to create difference instance of 2 versions
2. Identify workflows/scenarios in which you found improvement and scenarios which are important for your application(mostly used/heavy/important for client etc.)
3. Carry out performance test/load test on those scenarios on both versions
4. Measure response time for all pages as well as system metrics i.e. cpu,memory,paging,disk etc.
5. Based on both versions results, carry out analysis and compare the both the versions.

If required carry out performance tuning and optimization round to improve the results.
This was about strategy.

For tools,

1. Check Ganglia,munin,graphite,carbon,sar,perfmon,nmon for system metrics (if its a cluster then RRD tools like ganglia,munin are better and if its a single box instance then sar for linux will do and on windows perfmon will do.)
2. For Load testing, JMeter is better option but you have quite enough funding then go for loadrunner,neoload,rational performance tester and for cloud, try blazemeter
3. For J2EE level analysis, IBM health center is available (according to me very inefficient to use), JProfiler, yourkit, jvisualvm are available
4. For WAS, Performance Monitoring Infra. is available with standard options it has low overhead but if you increase the logging counters and levels and it has huge performance impact.

I hope things are clear now :)

Comment: Thanks. I checked the tools you mentioned, but none of them actually provide Java and JEE level analysis and comparing 2 applications.

Comment: modified the ans check now.

Comment: @NachiketKate I don't know where you found info that PMI has huge performance impact, but thats not true. Maybe you are mixing PMI with tracing.

Comment: @Gas : Actually I have used it on WAS many times for performance tuning, I have server class HW on which with custom perf counters I always found that it has quite impacting overhead. Application I have deployed is TIM which itself is heavy maybe what I observed is specific for TIM.

Comment: @NachiketKate I've used it many times during WAS tuning also. Unfortunately everything what starts with T is very heavy (e.g. TIM, TEP, etc) and shouldn't be compared and treated like products that starting with W ;)